# Spark Streaming reduceByKeyAndWindow with initial state

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

We have a streaming job that makes use of [`reduceByKeyAndWindow`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v1.4.0/streaming/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/streaming/dstream/PairDStreamFunctions.scala#L334-L341). We want this to work with an initial state. The idea is to avoid losing state if the streaming job is restarted, also to take historical data into account for the windows. But `reduceByKeyAndWindow` doesn't accept any `initialRDD` parameter like [`updateStateByKey`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v1.4.0/streaming/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/streaming/dstream/PairDStreamFunctions.scala#L435-L445) does.

The plan is to extend `reduceByKeyAndWindow` to accept an `initalRDDs` parameter, so that the DStream starts with those RDDs as initial value of `generatedRDD` rather than an empty map. But the `generatedRDD` is a private variable, so I'm bit confused on how to proceed with the plan.

Comment: could you add an example on how you would like to use this? Maybe `dstream.transform(rdd => rdd union initialRDD)` would be sufficient?

Comment: Basically I want my window to be composed of old data from the given rdd, and from new incoming data. Given my batch duration is 1s, and window duration is 10s, if I started the stream now and I had past 15 seconds data, after 1s I'd want my window to be composed of 9 seconds of old data and 1s of new data. (I don't think `dstream.transform(rdd => rdd union initialRDD)` is going to do that)

Comment: that means that you'd need not 1 but 15 rdds to "fill up" the window in the given example. Can't think of a way to do that, unless you'd refactor your process to use updateStateByKey and count windows somehow (maybe in the keys? w1, w2, w3, w4 ,...)